# kotlin firestore not updating my android app when new document is added

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore with some documents. when I run the app , the snapshot listener gets all the documents correctly , and afterwards it updates when there is a change in those documents.
if I add a new document through the console ( not by the app ) I don't get any notification about it , like I expected. did I miss something ?
this is the code for the snapshot listener:

```
val docRef = db.collection("pile").orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
val listener = docRef.addSnapshotListener() { value, e -> ... }
```

Comment: Have logged the message inside the `e` object? Do you get something printed out?

Comment: there is no response at all . it doesn't get to the error block.

Comment: So does any of the `value` or `e` contain any value?

Answer (score 1):

after few tries I understood that not all of my documents are downloaded even in the first "wave" of documents from firestore , and then I realized that because of the "orderBy" in my Query , the list I get every time must have this field ("time") inside of it.
and if I want to get updates , the new documents must also have this field.
so, when you try to test your firestore , don't be lazy and write all the fields , or at least those who are in your "orderBY" .